# How can i make VM to fully cover the screen in KVM?

Tags: display, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I installed Debian Wheezy in KVM using virtual machine manager. VM doesn't fully cover the screen, with large gaps in both sides of screen as seen in pictures below. How can i make VM to fully cover the screen in both full screen and non full screen modes?

Non full screen mode: [image]

Full screen mode:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start the VM using -std-vga flag and set the fullscreen resolution in your VM

Comment: Can I do it in Gnome Boxes?